# Easy way to undo changes made by multithread after each Spring Data JPA Integration Test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing

I know adding `@Transactional` can rollback the changes, however, my integration test involves multiple threads, and Hibernate is not happy to work with a single transaction shared between multiple threads, plus I need each thread to be able to see the changes made by other threads, so I ended up with threads having their own transactions and rolling back the starting testing thread does not undo the changes made by these threads.

Test database is started with TestContainer and I don't want to destroy the container as well, because tables are setup with Liquibase. So I am after some easy way to just wipe the data after each integration test.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way would be defining an `@AfterEach` method that calls `deleteAll` of the underlying repository or repositories:

```java
@AfterEach
void afterEach() {
  repo.deleteAll();
}
```

Comment: I also have some on the fly DDL (create table) so not everything can be removed by repositories.

Comment: Ok, then you can filter out the initial data (for example `deleteByIdNotIn(listOfIInitialds)`) or you can rerun liquidbase scripts which would be a more time-consuming solution.